# Spring Boot - PostMapping does not working

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am developing spring boot api project. `@PostMapping` annotation does not running. Why? I added breakpoint but not stopping?? Please help.

pom.xml

```xml
...
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
...
```

ApplicationUser.java

```java
public class ApplicationUser {
    private long id;
    private String name;

    // constructors, getters-setters
}
```

ApplicationUserController.java

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/users")
public class ApplicationUserController {
    public static final List<ApplicationUser> USERS = Arrays.asList(
        new ApplicationUser(1, "Jeff"),
        new ApplicationUser(2, "Mark"),
        new ApplicationUser(3, "Bill")
    );

    @GetMapping(value="/{userId}", produces="application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<ApplicationUser> getUser(@PathVariable("userId") Long userId) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(
            USERS.stream()
            .filter(user -> userId.equals(user.getId()))
            .findFirst()
            .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException(
                "User " + userId + "does not exists"
            ))
        );
    }

    @PostMapping(value="/add", consumes="application/json")
    public void addUser(@RequestBody ApplicationUser user) {
        for (long i = 0L; i < USERS.size(); i++)
            if (user.getId() == USERS.get((int)i).getId())
                throw new IllegalStateException("User " + user.getId() + " already exists");
        
        USERS.add(user);
    }
}
```

ApplicationSecurityConfig.java

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class ApplicationSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .httpBasic();
    }
}
```

I tried following command

```sh
~$ curl http://localhost:8080/api/v1/users/add -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' -d '{"id": 4, "name": "Steve"}' -u user:-spring-security-password-
(no response)
```

After was running above command, i tried followings

```sh
~$ curl http://localhost:8080/api/v1/users/1 -u user:-spring-security-password-
{"id":1,"name":"Jeff"}

~$ curl http://localhost:8080/api/v1/users/4 -u user:-spring-security-password-
{"timestamp":"2021-01-20T19:53:19.205+00:00","status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","message":"","path":"/api/v1/users/4"}
```

#### -- Edit --

I tried `POST` request with Postman, gets `401 Unauthorized`. When try `GET` request, runs properly.

Comment: `List.size()` returns an `int`.

Comment: Just a thought but could this be an issue with *how* you're using curl? Try another method, like postman, and see if you can still reproduce this.

Comment: @PeterMmm i changed all long & Long values to int & Integer but was not changed any stuff :(

Comment: @Jason i tried POST request with postman, postman says `401 Unauthorized`. When i try GET request with postman, runs properly.

Comment: Try to disable form login as well in your security configuration.

Answer (score 1):

List returned by `Arrays.asList()` does not support `add()`. If you still try to add, then it will throw `UnsupportedOperationException`.Try initializing a list as shown below.

```
public static final List<ApplicationUser> USERS = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
        new ApplicationUser(1, "Jeff"),
        new ApplicationUser(2, "Mark"),
        new ApplicationUser(3, "Bill")
    ));
```

Comment: Use `@Slf4j` on your restController and write `log.info(USERS.toString())`  in your `addUser()` method after `USERS.add(user);`. And then make a POST request. Hopefully, we can understand whats happening by looking at logs.